# Computing total amount of streamed content

Tags: architecture, streaming, scalability, cdn

Streaming content services like spotify, pandora, netflix etc. may be paying out royalties to the right holders based on how much content has been consumed by their users. This royalty computation model may be complex based on the negotiated contracts and some abuse prevention policies.

My question is how do we compute how much data is consumed?

**Approach #1:** 
Client applications such as consoles, apps, websites, send events/metrics to servers. These events can be start playback, end playback, total playback etc. And on the server we aggregate how much content is consumed. Then we feed this data to royalty computation.

*Cons*
- Abuse: We may end up paying more royalty, if abusers start sending non-legit consumption related events. We may be able to add some validations or encryption (on both ends - server and client) for verifying legitimacy; however, we won't probably be able to tamper the data stream.

**Approach#2:** 
If the content data (stream) is provided by the service provided directly (not through external CDN), then server side would know how much data is served and instead of relying on client metrics, we rely on service side metrics (which are more accurate). However, it's not scalable to have a server serve the content. Most scalable services would rely on CDN (Content delivery networks like Akamai) to deliver the content. And these external CDNs won't send out metrics about consumption at the granular level as required by the royalty systems.

No matter how much you make it fullproof, there's still chance for malicious users to break. e.g. in approach#2, we could still have bots playing content and generating royalties.

It would be great if folks could share their ideas/insights about this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1.

You mention "abuse" as a con to the client-initiated events. This kind of abuse kind of resembles AdSense click fraud. You could indeed worry about clients sending out "start" events without really pulling the content from the socket.

This is indeed a concern if the client is outside of your control, i.e. web players.

If you assume a secure client, you retain control over its behaviour and the concern is mitigated. By secure client I would look at:

- self developed app;
- with sufficient levels of encryption and authentication;
- deployed on decently protected mobile OS;
- through a thrustworthy distribution channel.

Ad 2.

Regardless whether you're counting the data consumption at the client or the server, there is always going to be the possibility that a stream is correctly opened and downloaded but never heard by an actual human being. I guess anyone can open the Spotify app and play with the volume at zero. But scaling this up does require bot development.

Protection can come from two sides:

- keeping control of the ecosystem (including the client), see above;
- account data analysis

Account data analysis is perhaps the most powerful mitigation against large-scale fraud. It doesn't make sense that 3000 new users, created on the same day, all listen exclusively to the same artist.

Comment: Thanks, Freek. I agree with your comment about types of clients (secured vs external).  And having customer analysis done is acceptable and is after the fact. However, I wanted to see if there's anything that can be done.